# Python: MemoryError

Tags: python-3.x

I have an error: MemoryError when I run the code in Python 3.5

```
unq, unq_idx = np.unique(targets, return_inverse=True)
unq_cnt = np.bincount(unq_idx)
cnt = np.max(unq_cnt)
n_targets = np.empty((cnt*len(unq),) + targets.shape[1:], targets.dtype)
n_input_patches = np.empty((cnt*len(unq),) + input_patches.shape[1:], input_patches.dtype)
for j in range(len(unq)):
    indices = np.random.choice(np.where(unq_idx==j)[0], cnt)
    n_targets[j*cnt:(j+1)*cnt] = targets[indices]
    n_input_patches[j*cnt:(j+1)*cnt] = input_patches[indices]
```

And the error:

```
 n_input_patches = np.empty((cnt*len(unq),) + input_patches.shape[1:], input_patches.dtype)
MemoryError
```

I didn't know what happen with the code. Please help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this exception is thrown when you are out of memory:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

Essentially your code is creating to many objects, so I would check your loops etc. or post the actual input for greater clarity.